# Columns are not added in datagridview in c# after data binding

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

I have a program in C# to read data from ".csv" and display in datagrid view. Main code for reading and displaying is shown below. It is executed upon button press.

```
StreamReader sr = null;
List<LogList> loglist = new List<LogList>();
BindingList<LogList> bindLogList;
BindingSource bLogsource;

dLogView.DataSource = null;
dLogView.Rows.Clear();
dLogView.Columns.Clear();

{
// code to add data to custom list
// the list has 12 fields.
     sr = new StreamReader("C:\\VSWR_T&M\\Log\\20200423.csv");
     int count = 0;
      // skip the first line read containing header, save from second line onwards.
     StringBuilder readLine = new StringBuilder(sr.ReadLine());
     if (readLine.ToString() != null && readLine.ToString() != "")
     {
          readLine = new StringBuilder(sr.ReadLine());
          while (readLine.ToString() != null && readLine.ToString() != "")
          {
              string[] subdata = readLine.ToString().Split(',');
              count = subdata.Length;
              LogList ll = new LogList(subdata[0], subdata[1], subdata[2], subdata[3], subdata[4], subdata[5], subdata[6], subdata[7], subdata[8], subdata[9], subdata[10], subdata[11]);
              loglist.Add(ll);
              readLine = new StringBuilder(sr.ReadLine());
          }
     }
}

bindLogList = new BindingList<LogList>(loglist);
bLogsource = new BindingSource(bindLogList, null);
dLogView.AutoGenerateColumns = true;  
dLogView.DataSource = bLogsource;    

dLogView.Columns[0].Width = 100;
dLogView.Columns[1].Width = 120; 
dLogView.Columns[2].Width = 50;
dLogView.Columns[3].Width = 50;
dLogView.Columns[4].Width = 50;
dLogView.Columns[5].Width = 50;
dLogView.Columns[6].Width = 50;
dLogView.Columns[7].Width = 50;
dLogView.Columns[8].Width = 50;
dLogView.Columns[9].Width = 50;
dLogView.Columns[10].Width = 50;
dLogView.Columns[11].Width = 50;
```

The LogList class is as follows:

```
class LogList
{
    string project { get; set; }
    string date_time { get; set; }
    string Qty { get; set; }
    string Pass { get; set; }
    string Fail { get; set; }
    string Result { get; set; }
    string ANT2_1 { get; set; }
    string ANT2_2 { get; set; }
    string ANT2_3 { get; set; }
    string ANT3_1 { get; set; }
    string ANT3_2 { get; set; }
    string ANT3_3 { get; set; }


    public LogList(string project, string date_time, string Qty, string Pass, string Fail, string Result, string ANT2_1, string ANT2_2,
        string ANT2_3, string ANT3_1, string ANT3_2, string ANT3_3)
    {
        this.project = project;
        this.date_time = date_time;
        this.Qty = Qty;
        this.Pass = Pass;
        this.Fail = Fail;
        this.Result = Result;
        this.ANT2_1 = ANT2_1;
        this.ANT2_2 = ANT2_2;
        this.ANT2_3 = ANT2_3;
        this.ANT3_1 = ANT3_1;
        this.ANT3_2 = ANT3_2;
        this.ANT3_3 = ANT3_3;
    }
}
```

When I run this code, I get exception message which says

```
"Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
  parameter name: Index"
```

Exception is generated from line

```
dLogView.Columns[1].Width = 120;
```

It seems the columns are not added. Am I missing some column property here ? I would like to know why the columns are not added ?

Comment: Please show the code for "code to add data to custom list"

Comment: I added the code to add data. It reads from ".csv" file. The first line is discarded and saving is started from second file.

Comment: I added DataPropertyName to each columns. Now exception is not shown but DataGridView is empty even when there is all data in data source of DataGridView.

Comment: *I added DataPropertyName to each columns*: you're clearing the Columns before you create the list, so that's irrelevant. Have you tried to simply add the `public` access modifier to your properties? e.g., `public string project { get; set; }`. `AutoGenerateColumns = true` is the default. You're using `[StreamReader].ReadLine()` in an unorthodox way in the `while` loop.

Comment: Try changing your column widths in `DataGridView.DataBindingComplete` event handler.